# Php: Mysql connect with ssh hostname

Tags: php, mysql

In my sql host environment when I try to connect to mysql I have to go through a ssh host. Here is my connection:

```
ssh hostname: server01
username : user
pwd: password

mysqlhostname : mysql01
port : 3306
username : mysqluser
pwd: mysqlpwd
```

How can I connect to the database in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. What you need to do is setup an SSH tunnel from your webserver to your SSH host and then use localhost with the port of your tunnel in PHP.

Comment: I found this code somewhere however it is not working , any comments :$connection = ssh2_connect('SERVER IP', 22); 

ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($connection, 'DESTINATION IP', 3307);

$db = new mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'DB_USERNAME', 'DB_PASSWORD', 
                         'dbname', 3307, $tunnel)
    or die ('Fail: '.mysql_error());

Comment: Thanks, I found solution for this problem, I moved to code to webserver which helped me bypassing ssh2.