# php mysql_connect(): How to connect to MySQL server through SSH tunnel

Tags: php, mysql

My MySQL server is being hosted somewhere outside and requires an ssh tunnel in order to reach it; how do I connect to this server through PHP? Has anyone experienced same problem before?

Comment: -1 for multi-posting (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003848/php-mysql-connect-with-ssh-hostname ).

Comment: Why do you need to connect through an SSH tunnel?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't but googling I found the following example:

```
<?php
  shell_exec("ssh -f -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 user@remote.rjmetrics.com sleep 60 >> logfile");         
  $db = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'sqluser', 'sqlpassword', 'rjmadmin', 3307);
?>
```

- It seems you first need to setup a ssh tunel (timeout of 60s). This works at OS level (shell_exec);
- In this example, your creating a SSH tunnel redirecting the **3306** port on the mysql host server to the port **3307** locally (webserver);
- You then connect (mysql_connect) as the mysql server were in your own webserver, redirect to the 3307 port.

I could't validate this solution, but I hope this helps you a step forward.

([Source](http://info.rjmetrics.com/blog/bid/44903/PHP-MySQL-and-SSH-Tunneling-Port-Forwarding))

Comment: Thank you J. Hudler for your response, wondering to setup ssh tunnel, I am using Eclipse an IDE for php development